Weighting procedure in longitudinal design
I am currently trying to figure out what to do but I can´t seem to find a proper solution. My problem is the following: I have a longitudinal design. For each day I have a variable stating whether an event occurred (1) or did not occur (0) and a variable to be answered in a 5 point Likert scale. This assessment was primarily done by phone (ecological momentary assessment). Unfortunately, sometimes the phone broke down and the participants filled out the different variables with a paper-pencil-form. That mean now I have for only a few participants for only a few days no phone but a paper assessment. I want to see whether I can merge those assessment methods together into 1 dataset. This means: Do the answers given to the questions differ based on the assessment method? But I have several difficulties: First of all, I only have a handful of paper assessments. Second, I have 4 groups which have different lengths in assessment periods (some have 16 days other 24 days). Third, I have varying number of days missing for the participants. Some have only 1 or 2 days missing in the phone assessment, some even more. When phone is missing only a few have a paper form and consequently paper is also incomplete for the time periods.
I wanted to see whether inverse probability weighting would be a possibility. I know that after weighting the merged sample I could use a general linear model (when I calculate the probability or mean across all days) or a generalised estimating equations (when every day has single entry).
I want to know whether this would be correct and whether there are other possibilities to compare the assessment methods when using the weighting procedure.
Thanks in advance!
